# Select is not displaying at all after binding data on it in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

I am trying to bind countries data into select option inside the sign-up form but after binding select disappeared completely. Here is the code:

**data model**

```
export class Countries {
    public name: string;
    public code: string;

    constructor(name: string, code: string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.code = code;

    }
  }


  export const country: Countries [] = [
    {
        "name": "United States",
        "code": "US"
    },
    {
        "name": "Netherlands",
        "code": "NL"
    },
    {
        "name": "United Kingdom",
        "code": "UK"
    },
]
```

I cut the whole data because it's too long for showing here. But it looks like this.

**Typescript**

```
import {country} from "../../models/countries.model"

...
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
country[];
 SignupForm: FormGroup;
...
ngOnInit() {
 this.nav.hide(); 
 this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
       'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])'),
       ]),
      'password': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}'),
       ]),
       'country': new FormControl([Validators.required,
         ]),
    });
}
```

I assume mistake should be in the TypeScript.
Also here is the HTML part:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group form-signup">
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password"/>
      <span *ngIf="!SignupForm.get('password').valid && SignupForm.get('password').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a valid password!</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-signup">
        <select class="form-control form-control-lg" *ngFor="let countries of country" [value]="countries.name" formControlName="country">
                <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option>   {{ countries.name }}
        </option>
        </select>
        <span *ngIf="!SignupForm.get('country').valid && SignupForm.get('country').touched" class="help-block">Please enter a country!</span>
  </div>
```

What is wrong? Why Select is disappeared completely and binding is not working? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 2):

you have to repeat `option` tag and not `select` tag :

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg">
       <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
       <option  *ngFor="let countries of country" [value]="countries.name" formControlName="country">  {{ countries.name }}  </option>
</select>
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for replying. Select appeared but data is not displaying in it. Seems the problem is with TypeScript. I've imported country from data model but in VS it shows passive which means it was imported but was not used.

Comment: the data is empty because you did not set its value when creating the `FormControl` , you have to set the value like this ,  `'country': new FormControl(countyValue, [Validators.required,
         ])`

Comment: countryValue is undefined :( 
it also shows a red line under country [] under the signup class

Comment: countryValue is just an example .. where is stored the list of your countries ? if it is stored in `country` variable , then you should create your `FormControl` as below :
`'country': new FormControl(country, [Validators.required, ])`

Comment: Error disappeared but data is not appearing in select again :( Something strange is happening here.

Comment: Can you update your post and add the code so we can know the reason , thanks

Comment: It's too long. All related parts are already added here: 
Data model file, Typescript, HTML

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ngDefaultControl` in **HTML**.
Also, include this in **TypeScript**: `countries:Countries[]=country;`

here is how should look like your code:

**TypeScript**

```
import {country, countries} from "../../models/countries.model"

...

export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
country[];
 SignupForm: FormGroup;
countries:Countries[]=country;

...

ngOnInit() {
 this.nav.hide(); 
 this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({

       ...

       'country': new FormControl(this.countries[0], [Validators.required, ]),
         ]),
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group form-signup">
        <select class="form-control form-control-lg">
            ...
            <option ngDefaultControl [ngValue]="country" *ngFor="let country of countries" formControlName="country">{{country.name}}</option>
     </select>
      </div>
```